# Azure Service Bus message receiver - loop vs stream

Tags: node.js, typescript, azureservicebus

I'm working on standing up the Azure Service Bus messaging infrastructure for my team, and I'm trying to establish best practices for developing Service Bus message receivers. We are standing up a new service to consume the Service Bus messages; the start up script will instantiate the message receivers and start their message reception.

The pattern I'm setting up for my team is to extend a base receiver class and implement an abstract function that will starts the message receiver in the stream fashion.

I'm curious if there are any notable differences between receiving messages using  `ServiceBusReceiver::subscribe` vs `ServiceBusReceiver::receiveMessages` (stream vs loop)? I'm suggesting that my team uses `ServiceBusReceiver::subscribe` since it registers the reception forever and it seems to handle errors more gracefully.

I've noticed two differences between the stream vs loop:

1. `ServiceBusReceiver::receiveMessages` is asynchronous. This means that in my script I would need to run `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled` to start the receivers in parallel. Because of the limited error handling with the loop message reception, I noticed that if the receiver hits an error, it will halt messaging processing. This scenario would require our team to restart the service if any of the receivers hits an error which is a con for our team.

The streaming method is synchronous so my start up script can register the subscriptions, save the return values, and close the subscriptions on shutdown.

2. If I refer to `this` object's properties in the `ServiceBusReceiver::subscribe` callback functions, I get an error that the property is undefined. It seems like the callback functions lose context of the object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The intended way of receiving messages is definitely streaming for the messaging services though both the ways of receiving work just fine with the ServiceBus JS SDK.

`receiveMessages` (loop) is more for the convenience of the users who just want to receive the messages simply and don't want to deal with the callbacks, handlers, etc.

Internally, `receiveMessages` also does streaming to receive the messages and waits for the given duration before returning the array of messages.

Hope that might clarify your doubts.

> If I refer to this object's properties in the ServiceBusReceiver::subscribe callback functions, I get an error that the property is undefined. It seems like the callback functions lose context of the object?

You can perhaps use arrow functions. For reference, please check this part of an unrelated `subscribe` test...
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/d417e93b53450b2660c34965ffa177f3d4d2f947/sdk/servicebus/perf-tests/service-bus/test/subscribe.spec.ts#L72